# maven resource filtering skipping files

Tags: java, maven

I got a Vaadin project with the following structure:

```
Project-Root
  src
    main
    resources
      properties.json
      META-INF
        persistance.xml
    webapp
      WEB-INF
        classes
          hibernate-dashboard.cfg.xml
          quartz.properties
```

Until now I built my project from my IDE (IntelliJ)

```
mvn vaadin:compile vaadin:compile-theme -P development
```

and then packaged the WAR with 'Build' -> 'Build Artifacts...' and deployed the WAR.

My resource filtering is the following:

```
..
<build>
 <resources>
     <resource>
         <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
     <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
     <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
 </resources>
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
     <configuration>
         <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

**Problem:** When I try to build the whole project with maven

```
mvn clean package -P development
```

the resources under webapp/WEB-INF/classes get skipped, they are in the target/Project/WEB-INF/classes directory, but the variables are ${..} (hibernate-dashboard.cfg.xml and quartz.properties)

The remaining resources (properties.json and persistance.xml) get filtered correctly.

**Question:** How can I filter all my resources and build/package my project with maven?

Comment: what's the problem/question?

Comment: What is the goal you bind the exectution of the maven-resource-plugin to?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle The only goals I got are under the vaadin-maven-plugin (update-widgetset and compile, tried adding resources tho). Edwin I updated the question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you're doing something very odd and should probably chose to change things so as to do things differently. The directory:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

should not exist -- you should not have a classes directory on that path. If you want filtered files to be placed into `target/.../WEB-INF/classes` then put those files in `src/main/resources` and maven will copy them to the appropriate target directory, and if you ask it nicely it'll filter them (populate the templates with values from the current context at the time of copying).

The only thing you really need is:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

If you think that you need a classes directory under there then you've probably made a mistake and the quickest way to fix this problem is by not doing the wrong thing any more, rather than trying to configure maven in this way.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I did not know that. I moved the files and it is working as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Maven only handles files in `src/main/resources` so I added

```
<configuration>
  <webResources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
          <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
```

to the maven-war-plugin and now I get a correct packaged WAR file.

Comment: Maven does use `src/main/resources` by default. But you configured resources plugin properly, so it does pick up those files; Sorry but I think your answer is incorrect and it only works incidentally (you moved filtering from `maven-resources-plugin` to `maven-war-plugin`)